# Why does a <b> split a text into two columns?

Tags: html, css

I have a strange behavior I cannot explain. I want to have a colored circle with some vertically and horizontally centered text in it where some words should be bold. The following example works fine if I just have text, but as soon as I add a  or anything to the text it's split into several columns.

Anyone care to explain (and help me fix it)?

```css
.circle1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;
  /* align vertical */
}
```

```html
<div class="circle1">
  <b>Lorem</b> ipsum bla bla bla <b>bla</b> bla bla bla bla
</div>
```

Comment: read this: https://dev.to/afif/never-make-your-text-container-a-flexbox-container-m9p

Comment: ^ never make a text container a flexbox container. Wrap everything inside a span or a div

Comment: if you could upload the sample image what is the expected, that would be helpful in getting in clarity

Comment: It's ot the `<b>` that makes it split, it's the `display: flex`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, so wrapping the text in a '<span>' does the trick. :-)